# Cs50-pset6-DNA.py does not pass check50 by only two

Tags: python, cs50

good afternoon my name is Daniel. Today I was doing dna.py from pset6, the object of this project is to identify a person from a given dna sequence. We are given a csv file which contains the need values to identify the person, ot has 4 columns: name, AGATC, AATG, TATC, these three last values are equal to the maximun times the str (AGATC for example) repeats consecutively (AGATCAGATCAGATC = 3)

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
```

An the dna sequence looks something like this:

```
AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG
```

When I was trying the program all the sequences were identified to the correct person, until I tried the code with sequences 15 and 18. When I run check50 it said that sequence 15 should be identified as "Sirius" put my program identified it as "Neville". After scratching my head for about an hour i could not find the problem so I wanted to ask if anyone know what it could be. Also I would really apreciate if you could also give me some feedback about the code, im still new to programming and to python so I will be glad to hear some advices or corrections.

```
# This program uses the sequence input as a command line argument and deciphers to 
# which person in the database is from
 
import csv
from sys import argv


def main():
    user_input()

# Checks if the user put the correct line arguments
# If command line arguments were input incorrectly return an error and print the correct usage


def user_input():
    while True:
        arg = len(argv)
        if arg != 3:
            print("Usage: python dna.py <data.csv> <sequence.txt>")
            exit(1)
        else:
            database()

# Opens the specified sequence and database


def database():
    datos = {}
    aga = 0
    aat = 0
    tat = 0
    
    # Opens database and copies it to a 2d list
    
    with open(argv[1]) as data:
        datos = list(csv.reader(data))

    # Opens the sequences and copies it as a string

    with open(argv[2]) as sequence:
        reader = sequence.read()
        p = 0
        max_aga = 0
        max_aat = 0
        max_tat = 0
        
        # Counts the amoun of times the STR repeats consecutively on the sequence
        # Counst the AGATC STR
        # Looks for the 'AGATC' pattern on the sequence        

        for p in range(len(reader)):
            q = p + 5
            tmp = reader.count("AGATC", p, q)
            if tmp == 1:
                aga = 1
                
                # Checks if the STR is consecutive one to another
                
                while True:
                    p += 5
                    q = p + 5
                    tmp = reader.count("AGATC", p, q)
                    if tmp == 1:
                        aga += 1
                    else:
                        if max_aga < aga:
                            max_aga = aga
                        break
        
        # Counts the AATG STR
        
        p = 0

        # Looks for the 'AATG' pattern on the sequence

        for p in range(len(reader)):
            q = p + 4
            tmp = reader.count("AATG", p, q)
            if tmp == 1:
                aat = 1
                
                # Checks if the STR is consecutive one to another
                
                while True:
                    p += 4
                    q = p + 4
                    tmp = reader.count("AATG", p, q)
                    if tmp == 1:
                        aat += 1
                    else:
                        if max_aat < aat:
                            max_aat = aat
                        break
                   
        # Counts the TATC STR          
                    
        p = 0    

        # Looks for the 'TATC' pattern on the sequence

        for p in range(len(reader)):
            q = p + 4
            tmp = reader.count("TATC", p, q)
            if tmp == 1:
                tat = 1
                
                # Checks if the STR is consecutive one to another
                
                while True:
                    p += 4
                    q = p + 4
                    tmp = reader.count("TATC", p, q)
                    if tmp == 1:
                        tat += 1
                    else:
                        if max_tat < tat:
                            max_tat = tat
                        break

    ag = False
    aa = False
    ta = False
    
    i = 1
    rows = len(datos)
    
    if rows > 4:
        u = 1
        j = 3
        n = 6
    else:
        u = 1
        j = 2
        n = 3
    
    # Compares the STR counts to the database
    
    for m in range(rows - 1):
        AGA = datos[i][u]
        AAT = datos[i][j]
        TAT = datos[i][n]
        
        if int(AGA) == max_aga:
            ag = True
            
        if int(AAT) == max_aat:
            aa = True
            
        if int(TAT) == max_tat:
            ta = True
        
        # If the comparison end as equal prints the name of the person
        
        if ag == True and aa == True and ta == True:
            print(datos[i][0])
            exit(0)
        i += 1
            
    # If the comparison ends as false prints no match found        
            
    print("No match")
    exit(1)
            

main()
```

Here i will leave the 15 sequence and the values corresponding to "Sirius"

```
Sirius,31,28,19
```

The sequence is reallyyyyy long so i will leave a small fragment so you can have an idea

```
GGGTGAATCTCGGACAAAAGGGACCCAGTAATGGGAAAACACCCTGTACTTTCATTTATCTTAAGGAAAAGGCACTGCGACTTGTGACTGTTTTGTGCTTACCGGTCTGCTGACCACCTCCGCAAGATTCACCGGGCCCTCGCC
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is "dna.py from pset6"? What is "check50"? We're not taking the same class that you are. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris thanks, I just edited it I hope I was able to explain it well